# is mysql license needed for sites like facebook,twitter

Tags: mysql, facebook, twitter, licensing

Is mysql license needed for sites like facebook, twitter etc.. i dont know which category they fall into. thats why.

Comment: Your question doesn't make any sense.  MySQL is open source and has nothing to do with facebook or twitter API's which is what I assume your asking about.

Comment: Yes it does make sense. I think he is asking whether facebook needs to buy a license to run their MySQL Servers (if they have any, no idea).

Comment: There are commercial editions ... http://www.mysql.com/products/

Comment: yes yankee . that's what i asked for

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because **it is about licensing or legal issues**, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274964/1402846) for details, and the [help/on-topic] for more.

Answer (score 2):

No, they can use GPL which is freely available. They would need to make Software that links to MySQL like a library or is even based on MySQL GPL, too, but as far as I know, they are not doing any of that. Even if, the GPL would force them to pass on the source code to anyone to whom they give the binary. Since they are not giving away the binary to anyone, there would not be a problem either ;-).