# Do I need to buy a MySQL DB server license for a facebook game

Tags: mysql, facebook, licensing

Maybe this is a duplicate question with this ([is mysql license needed for sites like facebook,twitter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4895708/is-mysql-license-needed-for-sites-like-facebook-twitter)) but I still want anyone who have experience on this to explain.

Here is my current situation, I wrote a game(PHP+MySQL), I want to moneitize by ads or the user buy the item with fb credit, so, what I understand is, if I don't share my code(...what code?), then I need to buy a license from MySQL AB, but do I really need to buy license? Anyone have experience on this? Please share, thanks a lot~!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because **it is about licensing or legal issues**, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274964/1402846) for details, and the [help/on-topic] for more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the only time you need to buy a license is if you want to distribute MySQL with your application (sort of like an embedded server).

Though, I would imagine sites like Facebook and Twitter purchased something completely different which is the "enterprise version", which also gets them support.

Comment: ha~thanks Nathan Adams, I don't have that skill/time to modify it's code:)

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: nope, Long answer: nope

Comment: hi yes 123, short reply: thanks, long reply: many thanks:)

Comment: you should have accepted nathan reply because it's the oldest here

Comment: yep, you're right, I got chaos because I'm sleepy last night when I tick the accept answer, thanks for your remind.

Answer (score 1):

As you are just using the MySQL binaries as provided, your not obliged to publish any code (You're not making any changes in MySQL sourcecode, do you).

As stated by @Nathan Adams you don't need a commerical licence if you don't want to resell an application with MySQL embedded.

Comment: Thanks freddy, that means only for community version, I can freely use it's binary, right~?

Comment: Yes - the community version is completely free to use in the manner you want to use it.

Comment: Yes, see http://mysql.com/downloads/mysql/ , on the right hand side

Comment: many thanks Nathan and freddy~ that means I can save my money to buy a IPad 2 :)